# Setting up database link from Oracle to Sybase

Tags: oracle, sap-ase

I know so little about Sybase that I don't even know whether database link is the correct term in Sybase. What I'm looking for is a way to communicate with Sybase over Oracle's heterogeneous services, commonly called a database link in Oracle (linked server if you speak SQL Server).

We are a primarily Oracle shop with a healthy dose of SQL Server, but zero Sybase experience. As you might guess, we have a piece of software that happens to run on Sybase, and we need to get information out of its database.

Professional services from the software vendor have not been helpful at all; frankly, we don't even know if they gave us the correct driver.

Our Oracle DBA is as sure as he can be (without knowing anything about Sybase) that he has everything set up correctly on the Oracle side.

When we try to run a query from Oracle to get data from Sybase, we get:

```
select * from call_request@sybase
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[SAP][ASE ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]Incorrect syntax near the
keyword 'where'.
{ZZZZZ,NativeErr = 156}
ORA-02063: preceding 3 lines from SYBASE
```

Complaining about syntax near "where" doesn't make much sense, since there is no predicate at all. And it doesn't help to add a dummy
`where 1=1`

We're completely unsure where to turn. What can we even check next? Where is the documentation for setting this sort of thing up? Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Which Sybase database product is this, Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere, Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise or Sybase Adaptive Server IQ.

Comment: I would add a dummy "where" clause just to appease the syntax error. Something like `where 1=1` should do it without affecting the query. Also since you're connecting over ODBC to Sybase have you tried using that with an ODBC client to retrieve data from Sybase.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that we get the same thing when we put ```where 1=1```. edited.

Don't know the version. Will find out.

Comment: Does an install directory of ase1600sp00pl02 mean that it is Adaptive Server Enterprise?

Comment: yes I would suspect so. `select @@version` would return a version string and definitely confirm it.

Comment: What happens If you execute a call_request directly in Sybase? Could be that the issue is in the remote code.

Comment: @access_granted FYI, call_request is a table, not a SP, so execute isn't the term I would have expected to see associated with it. However, running just "select * from call_request" works as expected when connected directly to the Sybase ASE server.

Comment: another crazy idea: try select * from <databasename>.dbo.call_request@sybase; and see if this yielded anything different. Database can be already in the tnsnames definition, but curious about addressing it directly.